# Jquery не получается сделать счетчик

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var counter = 0;
    $('.unload').click(function(){
        $('.block').eq(counter).css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
        if (counter < 9) {
        $('.block').eq(counter++).css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
        }       
    });
    $('.load').click(function(){
        $('.block').eq(counter--).css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
        if (counter > 9) {
            $('.block').eq(counter).css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
        }
    });
});
```

.unload - класс кнопки, который убирает элемент ;
.load - класс кнопки, который добавляет элемент.
Нельзя добавлять если уже есть 9 элементов, и нельзя удалять если удалены 9 элементов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем так сложно? На странице есть 9 элементов. Все, что нужно - это показать первый невидимый или спрятать последний видимый. А если таких нет, то не делать ничего

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.unload').click(function() {
    $('.block:visible:last').hide();
  });
  $('.load').click(function() {
    $('.block:hidden:first').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="load">Add</button>
<button class="unload">Remove</button>
<div class="block">1</div>
<div class="block">2</div>
<div class="block">3</div>
<div class="block">4</div>
<div class="block">5</div>
<div class="block">6</div>
<div class="block">7</div>
<div class="block">8</div>
<div class="block">9</div>
```